# how to write backend for contract if you use infura ropsten metamask and remix

Tags: remix, metamask, ropsten, infura, sendrawtransaction

i'm using metamask with ropsten. deployed my contract on ropsten using remix. for the backend i used infura to create instance of web3. 
ew Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/MY_API_KEY'));

i'm able to get data from blockchain by contract.getDetails(123);
but while sending the details i'm getting below error,
"The method eth_sendTransaction does not exist/is not available"

Answer (score 0):

I understand you problem, this is due to API version change between Infura and Web3. Please try to match the version of Web3 API with Infura.

Answer (score 0):

Install and use truffle-hdwallet-provider to create a provider using your **mnemonic** and the infura endpoint. You can then pass this provider while creating instance of Web3:

```js
const HDWalletProvider = require("truffle-hdwallet-provider");

const provider = new HDWalletProvider(
  mnemonic,
  'https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/MY_API_KEY'
);

const web3 = new Web3(provider);
```